# Display coordinates from kml

Tags: python, coordinates, kml, simplekml

I can't for the life of me figure out how to display coordinates from a simplekml file in Google Earth. I'm using a for loop to get coords from a list as such...

```
for code, label, lat, lon, mm, dte:
    pnt=kml.newpoint(name=label,coords=[(lon, lat)]
    pnt.description='PointA'
```

But I can't work out the formatting to actually display the coord's for each point. They are strings in the list ie.`[['AO1','Hway','-18.5','130.50',3.0,'30_3'],[ ]]` so I guess a formatting issue.... any suggestions?

Comment: When I say display, not the placemarker but in the balloon

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data
[['AO1', 'Hway', '-18.5', '130.50', 3.0, '30_3'], []]
```

Convert to float:

```
>>> float(data[0][2])
-18.5
```

Comment: Show exactly what the problem is. Why not just take the coordinates out of the list and convert them into floats if needed?